# Custom Parameters get cleared canvas to Json

Tags: json, canvas, parameters

I am adding svg to canvas and want to set custom Element Parameters. I shows custom parameter when we console log getActiveObject() but when we use canvas.toJSON() Element Parameter node values does not change.

```
var canvas              = new fabric.Canvas('designcontainer'),
/* Save additional attributes in Serialization */
var ElementParameters = { 
    ElementType:'',
    imageType:'',
    top:'',
    left:'',
    colors:'',
    isBaseTier:'',
    atLevel:''
};
fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function (toObject) {
return function () {        
    return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
        ElementParameters:{
            ElementType:'',
            imageType:'',
            top:'',
            left:'',
            colors:'',
            isBaseTier:'',
            atLevel:''
        },           
    });
};
})(fabric.Object.prototype.toObject);
/* End : Save additional attributes in Serialization */ 

var Designer = {
addElement: function(e,p){ /* e = element, image src | p = parameters set for image */
    if(p.imageType == "svg"){ 
        if(p.ElementType == "caketier"){
            var group = [];
            console.log('Before ');
            console.log(ElementParameters);
            $.extend(ElementParameters,p);
            console.log('After ');
            console.log(ElementParameters);
            fabric.loadSVGFromURL(e,function(objects,options){
                var shape = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects,options);
                var bound = shape.getBoundingRect();
                shape.set({
                    left: p.left,
                    top: p.top,
                    width:bound.width+2,
                    height:bound.height,
                    angle:0,
                    centeredScaling:true,
                    ElementParameters:ElementParameters
                });

                if(shape.paths && baseColor.length > 0){
                    for(var i = 0;i<shape.paths.length;i++) shape.paths[i].setFill(baseColor[i]);
                }
                canvas.add(shape);
                shape.setControlsVisibility(HideControls);
                canvas.renderAll(); 
            },function(item, object) {
                object.set('id',item.getAttribute('id'));
                group.push(object);
            });
        }
    }
}
}

$(".tierbox").on('click',function(){
    var i       = $(this).find('img'),
        src     = i.attr('src'),
        param   = i.data('parameters');
    Designer.addElement(src,param);
});
```

Now when I call JSON.stringify(json), Element Parameter node does not get overwrite with values set in shape.set() method.

Comment: Got solutions
replace fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function (toObject) { ... } 

To 

fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function (toObject) {
    return function () {     
        return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
         ElementParameters:this.ElementParameters
            });
    };
})(fabric.Object.prototype.toObject);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function (toObject) { ... } to

```
fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function (toObject) {
    return function () {        
        return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
            ElementParameters:this.ElementParameters
        });
     };
})(fabric.Object.prototype.toObject);
```

Comment: This causes another problem. If the object type is circle, then the radius is not stringified...

Comment: The correct solution is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66635306/custom-attributes-lost-after-applying-json-stringify-on-fabricjs-object