# Custom attributes lost after applying JSON.stringify on fabricjs object

Tags: javascript, json, fabricjs, stringify

I'm adding custom attributes to my fabric object as bellow and it works properly, but when converting the object to string with `JSON.stringify` it doesn't convert my added attributes

```js
var customcanva = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// my text object with custom attribute
text = new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', {
    attr0: 'value 0',
});

// with another custom attribute
text.attr1 = "value 1";

// object showing fine as json object 
console.log(text);

// stringified object doesn't have all attributes including my added ones
console.log(JSON.stringify(text));
```

I'm doing this so I can send my selected object via ajax request. How can I get my attributes persisted?

Answer (score 2):

When serializing a FabricJS object with custom attributes, the `toJSON()` method accepts an array of additional properties.

```
var text = new fabric.IText('Tap and Type');
    text.attr1 = 'red';
    text.attr2 = 'blue';

//pass an array of attribute names to the toJSON method
var json = text.toJSON(['attr1', 'attr2']);

//the output can then be stringified
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(json);
```

See here for documentation:
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#toJSON

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here's what I did. I converted my fabric object to a new json variable and added my attributes to it as below:

```js
text = new fabric.IText('Tap and Type');

// my new object
var newtext = text.toJSON();

// adding my attribute
newtext.attr1 = "value 1";

// object showing fine as json object 
console.log(newtext);

// stringified object showing with my added attributes
console.log(JSON.stringify(newtext));
```